# how to sort alphanumeric string in python with alphabetical order comes first?

Tags: python, sorting

I am dealing with a dictionary with alphanumeric key and I need to sort them.
The desired order is

```
a1 : 3
a2 : 2
b1 : 2
b2 : 3
c1 : 5
a1 b2 : 3
a2 b1 : 2
a1 c1 : 3
a2 c1 : 2
b1 c1 : 2
b2 c1 : 3
a1 b2 c1 : 3
a2 b1 c1 : 2
```

However, What i got so far is

```
 for key in sorted(s1.keys(),key = lambda item: (len(item),item,)):
      print("%s: %s" % (key, s1[key]))

 a1: 3
 a2: 2
 b1: 2
 b2: 3
 c1: 5
 a1 b2: 3
 a1 c1: 3
 a2 b1: 2
 a2 c1: 2
 b1 c1: 2
 b2 c1: 3
 a1 b2 c1: 3
 a2 b1 c1: 2
```

The thing is I want to go in the order of A->B->C->AB->AC->BC->ABC first then sort each small group according to the number value, for example, for AB, if I have a1b1,a2b1,a1b2,a2b2, then the order will be a1b1,a1b2,a2b1,a2b2.

Comment: have a look at groupby https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby. But I'm not sure that's going to be the most elegant solution.

Comment: Are letter and number always one digit? Is there always a space in between? Can there be letters without numbers or vice versa?

Comment: @tobias_k yes the format will always be a letter and a digit and a space in between

Answer (score 2):

As a `key` function, you could `split` and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) the keys:

```
>>> s = 'a1 b2 c1'
>>> list(zip(*s.split()))
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('1', '2', '1')]
```

To sort `b` before `a b`, you also have to take the number of segments into account.

For your `s1` data:

```
>>> sorted(s1, key=lambda s: (s.count(' '), list(zip(*s.split()))))
['a1',
 'a2',
 'b1',
 'b2',
 'c1',
 'a1 b2',
 'a2 b1',
 'a1 c1',
 'a2 c1',
 'b1 c1',
 'b2 c1',
 'a1 b2 c1',
 'a2 b1 c1']
```

If there can be more than one letter or digit per block, you could use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead:

```
>>> s = "aa12 bb34 cc56"
>>> re.findall("[a-z]+", s), re.findall("\d+", s)
(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], ['12', '34', '56'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to extend your approach and explicitly partition the letters and numbers in the creation of the sorting key:

```
d = {
'a1': 3,
'a2': 2,
'b1': 2,
'b2': 3,
'c1': 5,
'a1 b2': 3,
'a2 b1': 2,
'a1 c1': 3,
'a2 c1': 2,
'b1 c1': 2,
'b2 c1': 3,
'a1 b2 c1': 3,
'a2 b1 c1': 2
}

def fn(key):
    letters = key[0::3] #extract the "letter" part of the key
    idx = key[1::3] #extract the "numeric" part of the key

    #construct the composite key
    return (len(letters), letters, idx)

for key in sorted(d.keys(), key = fn):
    print(key, d[key])
```

produces

```
('a1', 3)
('a2', 2)
('b1', 2)
('b2', 3)
('c1', 5)
('a1 b2', 3)
('a2 b1', 2)
('a1 c1', 3)
('a2 c1', 2)
('b1 c1', 2)
('b2 c1', 3)
('a1 b2 c1', 3)
('a2 b1 c1', 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!